# On equivalence and congruence in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_q[X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $k$ denote the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q=p^n$ for some prime $p$.

Consider $f(X), g(X) \in k[X]$, satisfying $f(\alpha) = g(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in k$. I believe one can show that $m(X)\, | \,f(X) - g(X)$, where $m(X) = X^q - X \in k[X]$.

My question is about the generalization of the proposition above to the multivariate case. To be precise, let $f(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n), g(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) \in k[X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n]$, and let $m_i(X_i) = X_i^q-X_i \in k[X_i]$, $i=1,2,\dots, n$. Suppose that $f(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n) = g(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n)$ for arbitrary choice of $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1,\dots,n} \subset k$. I wonder if it it still true that $$f(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) - g(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)m_i(X_i)$$ for some $r_i(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) \in k[X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n]$, $i=1,2,\dots, n$? If so, how to prove it? If not, can anyone provide a counterexample?

Also, can anyone provide me with some brief references about multivariate polynomials over fields? Thanks in advance!

The problem occurs when reading Chapter $1$, *Number Theory* by Borevich and Shafarevich.

**Edit:** It seems to me now that one can generalize the one-variable proof to the general situation. Since $m_i(X_i)$'s are all monic, it is possible to define Euclidean division algorithm $$h(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) = q(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)m_i(X_i) + r_i(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$$ in $R_i[X_i]$, where $R_i = k[X_1,X_2,\dots, X_{i-1}, X_{i+1}, \dots, X_n]$. Notice that for $X_j$ with $j \neq i$, its degree in the residue $r_i$ never surpasses its degree in the dividend $h$.

Assume $h(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$ takes value $0$ for all possible values of variables. Apply long division repeatedly:

Step $1$: $h=q_1m_1+h_1$;

Step $i+1$: $h_i=q_{i+1}m_{i+1}+h_{i+1}$.

One obtains finally a remainder $r(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) = h_{n}$ with degree of each variable less than $q$. Because $r = 0$ for all values of variables, they must be identical by uniqueness of reduced polynomial.

Comment: This has been done before here on MSE. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4672283/polynomials-that-are-zero-as-functions-on-finite-fields?noredirect=1&lq=1) for instance though I wouldn't be surprised if there were other duplicates.